# Given $A$ is invertible, how to derive the characteristic and minimal polynomial of $A^n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given A an nxn invertible complex matrix; show how to derive the characteristic and minimal polynomials of $A^n$ from the characteristic and minimal polynomials of $A$.

I can see how easy this would be if $A$ were diagonalizable, but I don't understand what useful information '$A$ is invertible' gives us?

Comment: If $\text{Spec}(A) = \{\lambda_{i} \}_{i=1}^{n}$, then $\text{Spec}(A^{k}) = \{\lambda_{i}^{k} \}_{i=1}^{n}$

Comment: I don't know what Spec is, so this can't be the solution I am required to find.

Comment: Sorry [Spectrum of A is just the set of all eigenvalues of A], I meant if you know the eigenvalues of A you also know the eigenvalues for powers of A. Of course, the suggestion was made to make you think of how the characteristic polynomials of the two may be related.

Answer (score 1):

As akech wrote, the roots of $q(y)=\det(A^k-yI_n)$ are the $(\lambda_i^k)_i$ where the $(\lambda_i)_i$ are the roots of $p(x)=\det(A-xI_n)$; in particular, the previous polynomials have same degree. Thus it suffices to eliminate $x$ in the system $p(x)=0,x^k-y=0$. We can do that with hand or using the Maple library "Grobner basis" (recall that this software works over a commutative ring). For instance, when $p(x)=x^3-5x^2+4x-3$ and $k=13$, we obtain $q(y)=y^3-134892776y^2-1094609y-1594323$.

The case of the minimal polynomial $m_A$ of $A$ is more complicated because the degree may vary. We must see if there are $\lambda_i\not=\lambda_j$ s.t. $\lambda_i^k=\lambda_j^k$. For instance, let $A=diag(I_2+J_2,-I_3+J_3)$ where $J_p$ is the nilpotent Jordan block of dimension $p$; its minimal polynomial is $(x-1)^2(x+1)^3$; on the other hand, $A^2$ has $(y-1)^3$ as minimal polynomial.

Anyway, the first step is to eliminate $x$ in the system $m_A(x)=0,x^k-y=0$. Then $m_{A^k}(y)$ is a divisor of the result; according some tests with Maple, it seems that the result of elimination is the required minimal polynomial; to be checked...

It seems also that the hypothesis "$A$ invertible" is useless; for instance, the elimination of $x$ in $\{x^{50}=0,x^{13}-y=0\}$ gives $y^4=0$.